# Spring Boot log

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, logback

I have below code for SpringBoot log. It suppose to generate the file everyday no matter how large the file size is. But sometimes the log file not generated and sometimes the file include the other days log.
How can I solve this ? Is it because the file size not enough so log cannot be generated ?

Please help !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="./logs" />

    <appender name="SYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
        <syslogHost>10.0.3.20</syslogHost>
        <facility>SYSLOG</facility>
        <suffixPattern>abc [%thread] %logger %msg</suffixPattern>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-AUDIT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/abc.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/abc.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.rh.abc" level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

> For various technical reasons, rollovers are not clock-driven but depend on the arrival of logging events. For example, on 8th of March 2002, assuming the fileNamePattern is set to yyyy-MM-dd (daily rollover), the arrival of the first event after midnight will trigger a rollover. If there are no logging events during, say 23 minutes and 47 seconds after midnight, then rollover will actually occur at 00:23'47 AM on March 9th and not at 0:00 AM. Thus, depending on the arrival rate of events, rollovers might be triggered with some latency. However, regardless of the delay, the rollover algorithm is known to be correct, in the sense that all logging events generated during a certain period will be output in the correct file delimiting that period.

Check out the [`docs`](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) for more details.